# Add social media icon in header area

Tags: theme-development, social-sharing

I have  installed the [Swift Theme](http://swiftthemes.com/). I want to know how to put a social media button on the right of the logo. I have not much knowledge of theme editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread seems to answer your question http://swiftthemes.com/forums/showthread.php?1542-Social-Media-Icons-like-on-the-demo-page

1) Enable header ad
2) Insert some HTML to render the social media links and icons